# Colourful artifacts fly past my camera and I don`t why

Tags: rendering, particles, camera

I have been trying to create a ghost pianist animation in blender. Everything works perfectly fine, but then when I play my render, glowing artifacts fly past my camera. But when take a look at my animation in the viewport those flashing things or artifacts are not seen. They only appear in the render.

[image]

I have added a cube for the dust with a principled volume shader, I thought that might be the problem. So I removed the dust but the problem still persists.

The Blend file:
[image]

Comment: if you need more details or the project file just ask

Comment: please provide blend file. open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=bzGdWLeK" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/bzGdWLeK/)                              the project file

Comment: thank you. Can you please do "File"-> "external data" -> pack resources then save your blend file and upload again?

Comment: @chris i have packed the resources and everything but when I upload the file with the link you provided it says that the file could not be more than 30MB but my file is 60MB

Comment: I just rendered this at 50% after replacing the missing textures on the piano, and I'm not seeing the artifacts.  This makes me curious as to which version of blender you're using.  I rendered with 2.93.1.  Perhaps they're an artifact of you rendering at 70%?

Comment: @marty Fouts      I rendered my project using blender v2.93.0

Comment: Perhaps they're an artifact of you rendering at 70%? i am not sure

Comment: I've just rendered the project using v2.93.1 at 100%, after correcting the resolution from 980 to 1080 to match 1080p, and I can't find any artifacts.  sorry.

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestions marty fouts and sorry for the late reply